# hibernate @onetomany FK is not set

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 classes

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "user")
public class User 
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
private Collection<Book> userBooks;
}
@Entity 
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@ManyToOne
private User user;
}
```

here some more code:

> ```
>   User user = new User();
>     user.setUserName("Gleeb");
>     user.setUserPassword("gleeb");
> ```

```
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setTitle("some book ");
    book.setbookType(1);
    user.addUserbook(book);

    userService.save(user);
```

i am trying to create a new user and add a new book to it. 
when i save the user

> session.saveOrUpdate(user);

the user is saved, the book is saved 
but in the book table, the user_id is not set. and is left NULL.

why is that.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your code, but the join table was probably not populated because you forgot to initialize the user field of the book. in a bidirectional association, the owner side is the side which doesn't have the mappedBy attribute, and it's this side that JPA uses to know id the association exists or not.

Comment: i have added more code.
if i try to init the user memmber in book class i get exception:
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: Ok, i did not understand your sudgestion but eventually you were right. i had to put the new user i created inside the book instance. that's the only way it knew the user id.